# Missing Edit Option on Silverlight 4 DataForm

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I’m trying out the Silverlight 4 beta DataForm control. I don’t seem to be able to get the edit and paging options at the top of the control like I’ve seen in Silverlight 3 examples. Has something changed or am I doing something wrong? Here’s my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication7.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" xmlns:dataFormToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <dataFormToolkit:DataForm HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Name="myDataForm" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Movie movie = new Movie();  
            myDataForm.CurrentItem = movie; 
        }

        public enum Genres
        {
            Comedy,
            Fantasy,
            Drama,
            Thriller
        }

        public class Movie
        {
            public int MovieID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }
            public string Producer { get; set; }
            public Genres Genre { get; set; }
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of your code above is identical in VS2008+SL3.

The `DataForm` only provides the navigation bar if you provide it with a set of items assigned to the `ItemsSource` property.  By assigning directly to the `CurrentItem` property you are in effect asking the `DataForm` "please edit this item", which is exactly what its doing.

Answer (score 0):

AnthonyWJones is correct on the paging question. You need to bind to the collection to get the Next/Previous options.  I believe you need to implement IEditableObject for the View/Edit option to appear.